# Remove Order List Row Link in WooCommerce Admin?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, hooks, admin, list

I wanna remove the functionality of when you click on a order row in Orders in Admin, you will be sent to the edit page for that order.

I know it's added with jQuery in a js-file in the WooCommerce plugin. I have located the actual code:

```
/**
 * Click a row.
 */
WCOrdersTable.prototype.onRowClick = function( e ) {
    if ( $( e.target ).filter( 'a, a *, .no-link, .no-link *, button, button *' ).length ) {
        return true;
    }

    if ( window.getSelection && window.getSelection().toString().length ) {
        return true;
    }

    var $row = $( this ).closest( 'tr' ),
        href = $row.find( 'a.order-view' ).attr( 'href' );

    if ( href && href.length ) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if ( e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey ) {
            window.open( href, '_blank' );
        } else {
            window.location = href;
        }
    }
};
```

But I don't wanna change any code in the plugin. And there aren't js hooks or any php hook that can control that part of code.

So I guess the option is to add the `no-link` class to the columns in the list? How do I do that? I can't find anything about how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [`class-wc-admin-list-table-orders.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/admin/list-tables/class-wc-admin-list-table-orders.php) ([order column on line 173](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/admin/list-tables/class-wc-admin-list-table-orders.php#L173)) there doesn't seem to be a filter to change the markup.

To circumvent this, perhaps you could add a js/jQuery script, to `admin_footer` or with `admin_enqueue_scripts`, which either adds the necessary class(es), removes href or changes it to #, or with some [event delegation wizardry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17352104/multiple-js-event-handlers-on-single-element) have your own `click` event fire first and prevent the `WCOrdersTable window.location` from happening.

Comment: You are right. Maybe that's the options there is. And if I create other elements in a column, with the `no-link` class, that element wouldn't be "linked". So maybe that's what I should do instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can check here how to add no-link class into woocommerce order list row

orginal issue asked here https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/18704

orginal issue asked answer here https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/pull/18708